# Updated Screen Sizes Chart

Tags: android, google-play

Google provides a [chart of Android screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html), based on devices accessing the Android Market. Unfortunately, it's very old; it's from August 2010.

Is there somewhere I can find fresher data?

(Why do I ask? I'm pretty sure that the August chart is no longer accurate. It shows 45.9% of users having Normal/MDPI screens [i.e. 320x480 resolution], but there are almost no devices being sold in 2011 that have Normal/MDPI screens. Plus, the [version chart](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) updated in April 2011 indicates that over 90% of today's Android users have Android 2.x, but there are extremely few Normal/MDPI devices that support Android 2.x; most of them were stuck on Android 1.6.)

Comment: I can witness that here in Italy we have many LG Optimus One, it's 2.2, normal/mdpi, many have been sold around Xmas. Anyway I agree, it would be great to have new stats, maybe even localized.

Comment: The charts ARE kept up to date, maybe not enough of a breakdown though. See Fluffhead's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This chart of screen sizes is current as of at least March 2012.

http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html

Comment: Yes @Fluffhead is correct, the charts are kept up to date regularly.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer, but I have some statistics that may be helpful as the screen sizes can be understood from the device.
[image: Android Market Stats]

Comment: These are only for your app, though, right?  If so, this doesn't likely directly match the actual total Market stats - it just represents the folks interested in your app.

Comment: @Thane Anthem - right, just thought it may be a little helpful.